# simulate click in javascript (outside the window too..)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to simulate clicks dynamically, i already did it for three indented tree with this function :

```
document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        cursorX = e.pageX;
        cursorY = e.pageY;
}

function ret_vw(v) {
  var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
  return (v * w) / 100;
}

function simulateClick(x, y) {
    var s = d3.select(document.elementFromPoint(x, y));
    s.on("click")(s.datum());
}

function multiple_click() {
    //onmousemove = function(e){console.log("mouse location:", e.clientX, e.clientY)}
    if (cursorX >= ret_vw(15.25) && cursorX < ret_vw(42)) {
        simulateClick(cursorX + ret_vw(28) - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
        simulateClick(cursorX + ret_vw(56) - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
    }
    else if (cursorX >= ret_vw(43.25) && cursorX < ret_vw(70.25)) {
        simulateClick(cursorX - ret_vw(28) - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
        simulateClick(cursorX + ret_vw(28) - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
    }
    else if (cursorX >= ret_vw(71.25)) {
        simulateClick(cursorX - ret_vw(28) - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
        simulateClick(cursorX - ret_vw(56) - window.pageXOffset, cursorY - window.pageYOffset);
    }
    else
        console.log("no , cursorX = " + cursorX + " , cursorY = " + cursorY + " vw = " + ret_vw(15.25));
}
```

And it works for this below, if i click on one, it will click on the two others idented three :

(Without Click)

[image]

(With Click)

[image]

But i got two problem, if i push one of the indented tree outside of the window, it will not work, and secondly, i need to do it dynamically because i will not always have 3 indented three (i can have like two, four, five idented tree...)

Here is the picture for the case where my function multiple_click will not work (tree outside the window..) :

[image]

Thanks for the help guys !

(source of the idented tree with d3.js : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025)

Comment: What is the click supposed to do? If you're relying on on-screen click it might be problematic. Can you share the code that the click causes?

Comment: I added a picture to see the difference (without click and with), and added at the end the source of the idented tree. Hope it helps you to solve my problem :) @Shushan

Comment: Why are you driving this from a click rather than having control of your app and e.g. calling a function to do it, do you not have access to the code? Is this for functional tests?

Comment: When i click on one idented tree, i need to click to all others idented tree as well, so this is why i'm simulating the others click only when the user already clicked on one idented tree, and it's actually my code, but it's to long to show you everything (1k lines of code..) @Dominic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of using mouse events to trigger the click - which eventually calls this click function:

```
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

You would make a new mouseClick function which replaces the current one which happens on mouse click. 
This calls the current click function for all matching items. This is the concept:

```
function mouseClick(d) {
  // Assuming you have multiple roots (example only has root)

  for (root in roots) {
      // Find d in the current root (by name?)
      matching_d = ...  

      click(matching_d)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to finaly find a solution, well done !